# View Creation not showing data

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I have three views in one of my account.  The All data view shows what I assume is all traffic to the website.  The second view is the test view.  the only filter on that view is "Lowercase".  But for the same time frame it only shows some of the data of the first view.  then there is the third view I just created.  It has no filters yet it does not show any data at all.  Can anyone explain to me what is going on?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Views only  start tracking from the day - the minute -  they were created, they can't back-fill. So of course a view you just created doesn't show anything.